# Lifetime of static variable defined in Fragment Class in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, static, lifetime, static-variables

In my android application , I have multiple fragments associated with one activity, **What will be the scope of the static variables that I created inside the Fragment class?** In below example, Will "**isCompleted**" variable is destroyed once the Fragment got destroyed or will it have the scope of application!

My Fragment Class will looks like

```
public abstract class AbstractFragment extends Fragment {
    static boolean isCompleted;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Creation of View Code Will be here
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        //Destroy of View, Code Will be here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Static variables have globally(application) scope.**

**For example you can still use isCompleted from other fragments or activity even if the current fragment is destroyed.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).